# Running a program through C# with cmd doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, jmeter

I'm trying to run JMeter through C# with cmd but it just opens cmd and doesn't run anything.

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        //startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:";
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/k D:\\jmeter\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\bin\\ApacheJMeter.jar -n -t D:\\Delo\\dokument.jmx";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

That code just opens the cmd and nothing happens. I've tried changing the working directory but it doesn't work. If I don't set the working directory, cmd just open at my debug directory. This does work if I start it directly from cmd (without C#).

Solved with this: [a link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C?fid=1306563&df=90&mpp=10&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=4987497)

Comment: I manage to use this and it works now: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C?fid=1306563&df=90&mpp=10&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=4987497)

Comment: `k/` do you mean `/k` ?

Comment: I mean /k, after many fixes I guess I missed it. I figured out the problem with the link I posted in the first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to run .jar file directly via cmd interpreter, go for the following alternatives:

- use `jmeter.bat` wrapper script
- call Java executable like: `path\to\java.exe -jar D:\\jmeter\\apache-jmeter-2.13\\bin\\ApacheJMeter.jar ...`

I would also suggest using `-l` command line argument so .jtl results file could be generated.

See [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) article for details. I also believe that [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) will be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what are you trying to achieve, and why you aren't `using System.Diagnostics` ? But I have a suggestion if I understood you right:

```
>         System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

>         startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "D:";
>         startInfo.FileName = @"D:\jmeter\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar";
>         startInfo.Arguments = "";
>         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
> 
>         System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo2 = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
>         startInfo2.WorkingDirectory = "D:";
>         startInfo2.FileName = @"D:\Delo\dokument.jmx";
>         startInfo2.Arguments = "";
>         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo2);
```

Comment: I wanted to open a jmeter with dokument.jmx as paramater. I fixed it as I said in the first link. Thanks anyway.